# Version conflict - SpecFlow Visual Studio extension attempted to use SpecFlow code-behind generator 1.9, but project 'WpfApp3' references SpecFlow 3.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, compatibility, specflow, feature-file

I have installed latest version of Specflow(3.1.97), Nunit (3.1.97), MS Build Generator(3.1.97) in my visual studio 2017, I have created a feature file but its class file throwing errors.

I am getting below errors:

> Version conflict - SpecFlow Visual Studio extension attempted to use SpecFlow code-behind generator 1.9, but project 'WpfApp3' references SpecFlow 3.1.
>
> We recommend migrating to MSBuild code-behind generation to resolve this issue.
>
> For more information see https://specflow.org/documentation/Generate-Tests-from-MsBuild/

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to follow the link?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski: The question says they are using the latest version of SpecFlow with MS Build Generation.

Comment: The documentation the error message links to mentions a property of .feature files called **Custom Tool** (right-click on a .feature file, click properties). Make sure this value is empty. Also make sure the **Enable SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator CustomTool** setting in Tools -> SpecFlow is set to `False`.

Answer (score 1):

Please let me know if this works. I think I have had the same problem and it was hard to resolve.

Try clearing these two property fields of your feature file

[image]

And then rebuild

Comment: Mind marking it as answer so the backlog shows this question is answered :) ?

Comment: @KhusbooSaxena: see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).